# ajax response in input value attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

Commented response works properly, but I want to do something like `$('#total_products').attr('value') = response;` but this is not working. Why is this not working, and how can I resolve it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'product_store.php',
    data : {
      total_products: "totalproducts"
    },
    success:function(response) {
      $('#total_products').attr('value') = response;
      /*document.getElementById("total_products").value=response;*/
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("total_products").value(response);`

Comment: $('#total_products').attr('value',response)

Comment: thanks man it works.

Comment: $('#total_products').val(response);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#total_products').attr('value',response);
```

jQuery attr documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 6):

Although the above solution is right, the normal way to do this in jQuery is :

---

```
$('#total_products').val(response);
```